# Get all document sets from a library using its content type id CSOM Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have to get all document sets from a library using its content type id, using CSOM Powershell.
How to acheive this?Can anyone post some links related to this?

Regards
Swetha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get all document sets from one library by PowerShell script in SharePoint online.

The content type id of the document set is 0x0120D52000364A67128FA90B4FAA5D470A057AEC22.

There is a demo below for your reference.

```
$SiteUrl = "https://yoursite "
$UserName = "username"
$Password = "password"
$ListName="documentlibraryname"

$SecurePassword= ConvertTo-SecureString $Password –asplaintext –force 
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)  

 $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)  
 $Context.Credentials = $Credentials  
 $List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()) 
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.ExecuteQuery() 


foreach($item in $ListItems)
{


  if($item["ContentTypeId"] -like "0x0120D52000*")
   {

   write-host $item["ID"]
   write-host $item["Title"]

   write-host $item["ContentTypeId"]
   }

}
```

updated:

```
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite"

$ListName = "libraryname"

$FolderRelativeURL= "/sites/sitename/libraryname/foldername"


#Get Credentials to connect

$Cred = Get-Credential

    #Connect to PNP Online

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred


    #Get All Items from the Folder

    $CAMLQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>$FolderRelativeURL</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

    $FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $CAMLQuery

    Write-host "Total Number of Items in the Folder:" $FolderItems.Count

    ForEach($Item in $FolderItems)

    {

        if($Item["ContentTypeId"] -like "0x0120D52000*")
   {

   write-host $Item["ID"]
   write-host $Item["Title"]

   write-host $Item["ContentTypeId"]
   }

    }
```

Comment: My Document sets are inside folder.How can i get those from a folder?

Comment: we can use pnp powershell. I have updated the reply.